# Traversing and updating a complex Json file with PHP

Tags: php, json

I know PHP is not the most friendly language with Json but I'm trying to do something simple. I need to traverse a Json file, modify a few elements and save it. 
I am using `RecursiveIteratorIterator` and it traverses the array fine. 
I modify some elements (translate them, which work just fine) and then update them with the translation.
This code is meant for prsng Json files without any prior knowledge of their nodes.

Json:

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": [
                            "GML",
                            "XML"
                        ]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the code:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('file.json'), TRUE);
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
   new RecursiveArrayIterator($json),
   RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
   if(!is_array($val)) { 
     $xlation = mt($val,$lang, $apikey);  //this works fine
     $json[$key] = $xlation;
     }
 }

file_put_contents('translation.json', json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

And here's the resulting file, where the content is appended instead of updated.

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": [
                            "GML",
                            "XML"
                        ]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "title": "S",
    "ID": "SGML",
    "SortAs": "SGML",
    "GlossTerm": "Linguaggio di marcatura generalizzato standard",
    "Acronym": "SGML",
    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879: 1986",
    "para": "Un linguaggio di meta-markup, utilizzato per creare linguaggi di markup come DocBook.",
    "0": "GML",
    "1": "XML",
    "GlossSee": "markup"
}
```

Comment: Your `$key` value is only the current key, not all of the parent objects/array elements on top of it.  You'll want to somehow keep track of which sub-array you are in and the relationship to the `glossary` object/array so that instead of creating new "top level" array elements you are modifying the data that is in the existing array.  I'll play with it for a few and maybe post an answer w/ working code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting the key on the root `$json` variable every time, so it's effectively flattening it and overwriting any keys that might re-appear. You'd have to keep track of the nested key levels somehow.

Here's a [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#In_computer_science) example without an iterator below. I've just capitalized all the values in the JSON and then lowercased them to simulate your translation function call.

demo: https://3v4l.org/c6gWP

```
function process(array $element): array {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($element as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $result[$key] = process($value);  // recurse
        } else {
            $result[$key] = strtolower($value); // simulating "mt" translation function with "strtolower"
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$json = <<<JSON
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "EXAMPLE GLOSSARY",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "STANDARD GENERALIZED MARKUP LANGUAGE",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A META-MARKUP LANGUAGE, USED TO CREATE MARKUP LANGUAGES SUCH AS DOCBOOK.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": [
                            "GML",
                            "XML"
                        ]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "MARKUP"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
JSON;

$array = json_decode($json, true);
$result = process($array);
echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

> ```
> {
>     "glossary": {
>         "title": "example glossary",
>         "GlossDiv": {
>             "title": "s",
>             "GlossList": {
>                 "GlossEntry": {
>                     "ID": "sgml",
>                     "SortAs": "sgml",
>                     "GlossTerm": "standard generalized markup language",
>                     "Acronym": "sgml",
>                     "Abbrev": "iso 8879:1986",
>                     "GlossDef": {
>                         "para": "a meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as docbook.",
>                         "GlossSeeAlso": [
>                             "gml",
>                             "xml"
>                         ]
>                     },
>                     "GlossSee": "markup"
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Fantastic! That worked like a charm, much appreciated!